# Condition to test if a word exists in window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I want to test if a word ["sublanguageid-all" to be specific] is present in the current address of the page using an 'if' condition.
I've tried /sublanguageid-all/g, but I'm not able to put it in an if-statement

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('sublanguageid-all') != -1)
```

work?

Answer (score 2):

```
if( location.href.match("sublanguageid-all") ) { 
  alert('present') 
}
```

Comment: The match function takes, as its only argument, a regular expression, not a string - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/Match

Answer (score 0):

you can simply try the includes(). Kindly refer following code.

```
if(window.location.href.includes('sublanguageid-all')) {
    // your code while it exists in the URL
}
```