# jquery how to check if url contains word?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to check if url contains the word catalogue.

This is what i am trying...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("catalogue"))
        {
            $("#trail").toggle();
        }
    });
```

The url of the site could be..

```
http://site.co.uk/catalogue/
```

Or

```
http://site.co.uk/catalogue/2/domestic-rainwater.html
```

etc.

But it doesn't work. Can somebody please point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: change if (window.location.href.indexOf("catalogue")) to if (window.location.href.indexOf("catalogue") > -1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897903/condition-to-test-if-a-word-exists-in-window-location-href

Comment: Did you try the [`.indexOf()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577480/javascript-for-conditional-url-append-or-redirect-based-on-window-location-href

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("catalogue") > -1) { // etc
```

indexOf doesn't return true/false, it returns the location of the search string in the string; or -1 if not found.

Comment: `!= -1` would be much better for `indexOf`

Comment: @Vega I'm not sure I'd agree that it's *much* better.  The result is the same `> -1` requires 1 less character.  If that code is on a site with 1million requests a day that's quite a bandwidth saving! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as the OP was already looking for a boolean result, an alternative solution could be:

```
if (~window.location.href.indexOf("catalogue")) {
    // do something
}
```

The tilde (`~`) is a bitwise NOT operator and does the following:

`~n == -(n+1)`

In simple terms, the above formula converts -1 to 0, making it falsy, and anything else becomes a non-zero value making it truthy. So, you can treat the results of `indexOf` as boolean.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the includes(). Kindly refer the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.includes('catalogue')) {
        $("#trail").toggle();
    }
});
```