# hide element based on URL href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to hide an element based on the `window.location.href` object. My approach is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowURL = window.location.href;

  if (windowURL.indexOf('stackoverflow') > -1) {
   $('#hide-this').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
#hide-this {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#show-this {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hide-this"></div>
<div id="show-this"></div>
```

The expected result is to hide the red square. However it still shows. I'm a little lost as to what I'm doing wrong, as this seems pretty basic/straightforward...It's probably something small that I'm missing. any help would be appreciated.

Here is a JSfiddle as well demonstrating the same issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ce86zb3r/8/

UPDATE: Looks like the code is having trouble here in this specific context due to iFrames, but it doesn't work on the site I'm working on, despite the URL being correct when `console.log`ed - why would that be?

FINAL UPDATE: I was editing the wrong file. Lol...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ce86zb3r/13/ code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243576/jquery-how-to-check-if-url-contains-word)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery how to check if url contains word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243576/jquery-how-to-check-if-url-contains-word)

Comment: you are getting -1 so it will not go in If condition

Comment: check for the windowURL  in console and then make the condition for it in your website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `console.log` the `windowUrl` variable, you will see that it is not the StackOverflow page, but https://stacksnippets.net/js (which provides the snippet embedded into SO) instead. So, changing the string to be searched to "stacksnippets", it works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var windowURL = window.location.href;
   console.log(windowURL);

   if (windowURL.indexOf('stacksnippets') > -1) {
     $('#hide-this').css('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

```css
#hide-this {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#show-this {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hide-this"></div>
<div id="show-this"></div>
```

Your code is fine. You just need to make sure you are using a text from the URL of the embedded page instead of the page which is embedding it.

Comment: good explanation ..

Comment: Thanks for this that makes sense in this context. In my real world example (which sadly I cannot share since it's not available to public yet) I basically need to hide an element when a specific set of characters within the URL is present. What would be an reason of this code not working, when I `console.log` the `windowURL` variable and it returns the correct URL?

Comment: It depends on the string you are searching in `indexOf`. Are you sure it is a substring considering the case (uppercase, lowercase)? If it is, it would work. If you can share the URL and the string used for the search, it would make easier for us to help you

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares what I can say is running this code directly in console works. I need to figure out how to fire it - the string I'm looking for is generated by a search feature.

Answer (score 0):

For your fiddle, the iFrame that displays the results has a url contaiing jshell

I have updated your fiddle and shown it working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ce86zb3r/12/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var windowURL = window.location.href;

if (windowURL.indexOf('jshell') > -1) {
    $('#hide-this').css('display', 'none');
}
});
```